# Transmit FTP ignore files

Tags: svn, filter, ftp

Is there an ignore or filter list in Transmit when ftping files?  I would like it to ignore uploading .svn files and such.

Comment: Please provide some additional infomation, do you want to apply this filter serverside or to your client and what software you are using?

Comment: I'm referring to Panic Transmit (http://www.panic.com/transmit/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Go to the preferences and select the `Rules` tab. There you can define rules for what files to skip. Actually, unless you've changed it version control directories like .svn and .git are already predefined for you.

Comment: Where in Preferences do I create these rules?

Comment: I had an old version of the software.  I see it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned go to **Preferences** > **Rules**. It should be noted that although the option says **Skip *Files*** I can confirm that it includes *folders* as well.

Here is an example set of rules that would be a good start that I use based on Transmit's defaults.

[image: Transmit rules]

Answer (score 0):

I was about getting crazy with this because it didn't worked - than I found this option that is unchecked by default.

[image]